# form object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Tags: python, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to generate a form using django documentation. I am continously getting the error:

```
'TestForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

even though `form.is_valid` is `True` (it prints the 'form is valid' line of my code).  Following are the relevant portions of my code.

*urls.py*

```python
url(r'^test/',views.test),
```

*forms.py*

```python
from django import forms
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

*views.py*

```python
def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            print 'form is valid'
            print form.cleaned_data                       
        else:
            print 'form not valid'
    else:
         form = TestForm()

    return render_to_response('User/Test.html',{'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*Test.html*

```html
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are not triggering the cleaning and validation of the form, this is made by calling the `is_valid()` method (note the parentheses **`()`** ), that's why you have no cleaned data.

Correction:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = TestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print 'form is valid'
        print form.cleaned_data
    ...
```

Comment: ,Thank u for your post,I corrected it to is_valid(),now  if form.is_valid is False,it enters to else part of the code.

Comment: +1 for the () catch.  I had same issue and the tricky part is that it worked if I set a break point and stepped through the code, but wouldn't work otherwise.  Guessing the debugger forced the form object to fully populate even without the is_valid() call.

Comment: It is an odd system. I wanted to use the cleaned data, but use my own validation (because it required conditional validation), so I had to call the is_valid() function and then not use what it returns.